# EF Core - Include multiple child tables

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Im trying to load multiple related child tables (table B and B1, B2), but ThenInclude works only for one child table. Im using EF Core 3.1, any idea how to do it?

This way works for one child table:

```
var result = context.A
  .Include(x => x.B)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.B1);
```

But I want to load related not only from table B1, but from B2 too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLsI4.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to repeat Include again

```cs
var result = context.A
  .Include(x => x.B)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.B1)
  .Include(x => x.B)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.B2);
```